# dojo FilteringSelect from URL default value

Tags: url, dojo, default-value

Hi I have a working FilteringSelect which reads from a URL.  Entering names will query the database and return the appropriate JSON to populate the filtering select, I can select a value and it stores the ID.

```
<div data-dojo-type="ComboBoxReadStore" data-dojo-id="assignedUserIdstore"
data-dojo-props="url:'Welcome.do?call=JS&actionRefId=142',
requestMethod:'get'"></div>

<input id='assignedUserId' name='value(assignedUserId)'
data-dojo-type='dijit.form.FilteringSelect'
data-dojo-props="store:assignedUserIdstore, pageSize:5,  labelAttr:
'label',queryExpr: '*${0}*', autoComplete: false" />
```

The issue comes with setting the default value.  I have this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>dojo.ready(function(  
  {dijit.byId('assignedUserId').setValue('25');});
</script>
```

This appears to work after a fashion - it does call the server and the server returns this

{ "id":"25", "name":"John Smith"  "label":"John Smith"}

However it does nothing to actually populate the filtering select with neither a display nor an actual value for the input.  I tried to set the value to the name but that had no effect either.  Having it return a collection instead of a single item does not help either.

The comboreadstore is defined as

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

          require([
                  "dojo/_base/declare",
                  "dojox/data/QueryReadStore",
                  "dojo/parser",
                  "dijit/form/FilteringSelect"],

                  function(declare, QueryReadStore){

                          declare("ComboBoxReadStore", QueryReadStore, {
                                  fetch:function(request) {
                                          // This results in a xhr request to the following URL (in case of GET):
                                          //      /url.php?q=<searchString> 
                                          request.serverQuery = {q:request.query.name};
                                           return this.inherited("fetch", arguments);
                                  }
                          });

                  }
          );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dojo.ready doesn't guarantee that the data you're fetching is ready/loaded. It does fire when dojo is ready and all your required assets have been loaded. So i think you're trying to set the FilteringSelect to a value which doesn't exist in the store yet. You could solve this by waiting with setting the value untill the store is ready. How to do that depends on the store you are using which i can't really make up out of your code. I'm not familiar with ComboBoxReadStore. After some googling i found out it might be an extension of dojox.data.QueryReadStore, which is outdated and unfinished. If so i'de suggest you switch to using [dojo.store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/store.html#dojo-store) if possible.

Furthermore: The setValue method on dijits is deprecated, you should be using set('key', val).

Comment: Right but is the functionality of a simple URL and pass parameters of what you type (or an ID) not implemented.  Looking at dojo.store it seems I have to setup a completely different architecture to support this and I am not finding too many examples.

Comment: I've setup a little example for you. FilteringSelect with a JsonRest store actually works easier than what you are doing at the moment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9WoWlE?p=preview (mind the example doesn't really work because plunker obviously can't return api calls, but you can check your inspector's network window to see it at work)